Issue with Batch Block in AnyLogic Process Flow
Problem:
I have modeled a process flow in AnyLogic where incoming orders are collected in a batch block. Before adding the batch block, my process flow worked fine and delivered the orders. Now, it stops at the moveTo block. I understand that when creating a batch, it does not inherit the parameters of the incoming agents. Therefore, I added the following lines of code in the batch:.
Despite this, my moveTo block receives the orders but doesn't deliver them. Here is my prozessflow: 
My Customer sends the order to the CollectionPoint .
Could someone please help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

any error msg? Else, what do you get traceln-ing the batch.transshipment in the beginning of the move-to block? Figure out where stuff gets lost first :)

Thank your for your response.
No, I don't get an error message.  For some reason I can't trace batch.transshipment, only agent.transshipment or batch.
I wrote traceln("Batch orders: " + batch.transshipment); and get an error that the transshipment cannot be resolved.

You likely aren't batching into the agent type you think you are. Amend the original question with screenshots of the order type, batched agent type and the batch block properties

(or if you cannot edit the original: delete it and open a new issue with full details)

I checked again and didn't see the mistake. I added the Screenshots you asked for. Thank you for the help!

tried "permanent batch"?
